# I have two groups of system notification icons

Tags: unity, panel, notification-area

I'm newbie in Ubuntu, after install Ubuntu 16.10, I have groups of system notification icons at top right desktop screen (clock, battery icon, volume, language bar, etc.).

You can see a screenshot showing the two groups of system notification icons in Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: There probably shouldn't be any serious problems. If it really matters, you might be able to right-click->delete them. *DO NOT CLICK "DELETE TOOLBAR"*.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for you comment but right click is not allowd.
My Problem solved, Problem is of Nvidia Graphic Card Driver.
I change my graphic card driver and solved!

**Edited - Added More Details**

Sorry for my english.

By Default Ubuntu use **X.Org X server** driver, but i change my driver to **nVidia Binary Driver v367.57**.

**BUT** i try many times to reinstall Ubuntu and finally i found the problem !

Yeap, in **System Setttings > Displays** i have Two monitor and with another driver Three monitor:

1. Built-in Display
2. Unknown Display

If both of them is ON , Ubuntu have many problems, for example I had another problem with Telegram Software, after run Telegram i can see Telegram Icon in system tray icon but the main window will not be displayed ! because this program is in another monitor (**Unknown Display**) so we can't see that.

I just turn off **Unknown Display** and used just **One Monitor** (I try Built-in Display)

Turned Off Unknown Monitor
[image: Turned Off Unknown Monitor]

Turned On Built-in Monitor
[image: Turned On Built-in Monitor]

Comment: Could you update your answer with the bad and good driver names for you? Also the model of your card. This might help others. Thank you.